# AnchorPane scrollinh in javafx

Tags: javafx

In my application iam using table view it consists large table column iam unable to scroll anchorpane to view more table column at run time in javafx fxml.

Comment: can you add an image ?

Comment: or even better, some code ?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to know how to add scrolling support to your table view.
Replace or wrap the `AnchorPane` in a `ScrollPane`.